# allauth is redirecting me to /accounts/profile when i am trying to go to /accounts/login

Tags: django

I have done all the necessary settings in settings.py, and i have set the urls too i the urls.py file. Each time i am trying to access /accconts/login, it will say the url did not match any pattern, and it redirects me to /accounts/profile. 
This are the code

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sites',

'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'allauth.socialaccount',

'core'
```

]

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

SITE_ID = 1

urlpatterns = [
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls'))
    ]
```

Comment: set `LOGIN_URL = 'accounts/login'` in settings.py

Comment: Not working sir

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. I was able to solve the problem. The way allauth works you must not be logged in while accessing /accounts/login.
What i did was to go to /accounts/logout/ and then logout before the /accounts/login will go

Answer (score 1):

By default **django-allauth** divert logged in users from the login page.

You can use a couple of *settings* to fix the issue :

1. SET the `ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATED_LOGIN_REDIRECTS` to FALSE
   or
2. SET `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to `'the desired path'` for logged in users in the `settings.py` file.

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

General remark: the behavior is pretty confusing. Usually want you want is a redirect to the page where the login was started from. It's not trivial to achieve this for all possible user login actions. Do the following:

**Part 1:** views.py

In `views.py` work with classes like this. They will handle everything for you as expected by adding `?next=...` in the url.

```
   class BaseView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
      login_url = '/accounts/login/'

      def get(self, request, id=None):
      ...
```

If you have no explicit login links in your templates you are already done.

**Part 2:** settings.py

Optionally specify what to do if ?next is not given. Do this by, e.g.

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`

**Part 3:** html

If you have somewhere `{% url 'account_login' %}` in your htmls and you're not fine with `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` manually specify the next variable e.g.

`{% url 'account_login' %}?next={% url 'my_profile' %}`